# DLTK TCL Project importing problems

Tags: java, eclipse, tcl, emf, dltk

I am having problems importing the TCL-DLTK project into my IDE (Eclipse).

I did clone the git repo, but I get warnings and errors on imported projects :

On org.eclipse.dltk.tcl.activeStateDebugger Project, I get the warning

> Discouraged access: The type CheckedListDialogField is not accessible due to restriction on required library ...\plugins\org.eclipse.dltk.ui_4.0.0.201206120848.jar " on some import instructions.

I also get this error

> The constructor TclSpawnpointPreferenceBlock(new IShellProvider(){}, TclActiveStateDebuggerBlock) is undefined" in TclActiveStateDebuggerBlock Class.

An other example is in the org.eclipse.dltk.tcl.core project where I get this error

> The import org.eclipse.dltk.compiler.SourceElementRequestorMode cannot be resolved" on the  org.eclipse.dltk.tcl.internal.structure/TclSourceElementParser2 Class.

To sum up, almost every project contains errors.

I am working with Eclipse Juno with DLTK and EMF plugin Installed.
I appreciate any help you could provide.

Comment: If it is the latest source it probably requires DLTK 5.0

Comment: thanks, that have solved partly the problem.Now I don't have code errors but rather errors marks on projects. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I looked into the Problems View, And the problem mentionned is " An API baseline has not been set for the current workspace ". What API do they mean ?

Comment: Look at `Preferences > Plug-in Development > API Baselines`

Comment: Could you please post your solution so that I could accept it as the answer for this question :) ?

Comment: OK, added a slightly expanded answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest source will require the current DLTK release - 5.0

You set up API Baselines in `Preferences > Plug-in Development > API Baselines` (you can also turn off the warning in the same place). The API Baseline provides additional checks that you are using the code as intended.